# Is there a problem with two people lighting a double chanukiah?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, menora-chanukia

Is there a problem with two people lighting from a chanukiah that has two Shamashes and 16 candles? Say, Shamash, 8 candles, Shamash, 8 candles, all on one structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 139 (6)](http://www.chabad.org.il/Articles/Article.asp?ArticleID=1267&CategoryID=170)

> וצריכין ליזהר שיתן כל אחד ואחד נרותיו במקום מיוחד, כדי שיהיה היכר כמה
>   נרות מדליקין

or as [Ohr Someach](http://ohr.edu/1304) expresses the halacha:

> If a number of people are lighting in one household they should make a
>   slight separation between their menorahs so that there is no confusion
>   to the observer as to the number of candles.

So there is a problem with two people lighting from a double chanukiah.

Comment: No, quite opposite. The KSA only requires separation between *groups of candles*, not candelabras.