# Menorah with uneven spacing

Tags: halacha, minhag, calendar, chanuka, menora-chanukia

The following assumes lighting an additional candle for each day of Chanukkah:

Two may light in a single Menorah for the first three days of Chanukkah; each in his end of the Menorah. This does not work for the fourth day, since it would be impossible to tell if it is the fourth day (two people lighting) or eighth day (single person lighting).

Clearly, it is a requirement to be able to deduce the current day. ([Kitzur Shulchan Oruch 139 (6)](http://www.chabad.org.il/Articles/Article.asp?ArticleID=1267&CategoryID=170))

Many Menoros have the Shamash dividing the eight candles into two groups of four: [image: In-line Menorah]

Some have the Shamash offset to the side, but still  have larger spacing in the middle. [image: Offset Menorah]

How are we allowed to use such Menoros?

Comment: Can you cite a source for "Two may light in a single Menorah for the first three days of Chanukkah; each in his end of the Menorah"? I seem vaguely to recall seeing the contrary.

Comment: "Clearly, it is a requirement to be able to deduce the current day." Source? Why would it actually matter what day it is?

Comment: What @msh210 said. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50672/is-there-a-problem-with-two-people-lighting-a-double-chanukiah -- if two people can't light on one with 16 candles, surely two people can't use a single chanukiah.

Comment: @DoubleAA See Scimonster's reference כדי שיהיה היכר כמה נרות מדליקין.